# How can I make slit-scan photographs with a dSLR?

Tags: technique, video, shutter

Surfing the web, I stumbled on an [iPhone application to make slit-scan images](http://funnerlabs.com/apps/slitscan). However, I have no intention of buying a smartphone.

How could one achieve similar results using a dSLR (preferably, but not necessarily, in-camera)?

Comment: yep but dont talk about the sheep? not ready?

Comment: Magic Lantern has the ability but it might be only for video, I've been meaning to try messing around with this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what it is you want to photograph, producing a slit-scan image can either be trivial (done wholly in camera), or somewhat difficult (require various contraptions).

Most modern dslr's use a "rolling shutter" which in effect, emulates the slit-scan technique used by cinematographers.

The effect of which is very pronounced when using a dSLR that also shoots video. The so called "jello effect."

So, if you want to try making slit-scan photographs, you can take a photo of something fast (like an airplane propeller), or shake or [throw the camera](http://cameratoss.blogspot.com/2005/10/camera-toss-mini-howto.html) while taking the picture.

Otherwise, you'll need to set your dlsr on long exposure, and [setup your own "slit" shutter](http://jpglprojects.com/2010/02/03/diy-slit-scan/).

Personally I'd just pony up for an iphone and buy the $1.99 app, rather than toss my camera around or build a shutter system ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a video capable camera, I can think of the following way:

1. Shoot a video clip for the required period.
2. Decompose the videos into single frames.
3. Upload frames to an image editing software that supports scripting - or -
4. Upload frames (or video clip) into Matlab.
5. Compose a new frame from consecutive scan rows from consecutive frames.

Voila!