# How can I make a high resolution Slit Scan photograph with Magic Lantern

Tags: magic-lantern

I guess the subject says it all. I've read [How can I make slit-scan photographs with a dSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11557/how-can-i-make-slit-scan-photographs-with-a-dslr) and I love messing about with slit scan with an app on my iPhone but I want to make one with my Canon 5D Mkii running Magic Lantern. It has been months since I looked at the Magic Lantern Forums and I did't find an answer there.

Here's one I just threw together with my iPhone app.

[image]

I'll be spending some bounty points on this, at least 150, maybe 200, I don't want to drop below 4K. (And yes, I'll edit this comment out when I post the bounty.)

Comment: I'd love to be proved be wrong here but (so far as I know) the time a shutter curtain takes to travel is fixed and the interval between the two curtains starting their movements change with shutter speed.  That means the only way you could do anything similar is for magic lantern to shoot a video then produce a slit scan image from that.  That's probably what the iPhone app does.

Comment: In previous versions of ML this function was present for photo taking as well. In `Silent Picture` mode it would read out the Liveview frame line by line. This does mean that you were still limited to [1720x974](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Unified/UserGuide#Shoot). However I see in the [change log](https://bitbucket.org/hudson/magic-lantern/commits/all?search=slit) that this feature is removed from ML in March 2012 and that you are left with the video method + frame grabbing + still a low resolution. I think the conclusion is that you can't take a high res slit-scan photo with ML.

Comment: Hmmm, might as well make that an answer then, boo, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In previous versions of ML this function was present for photo taking as well. In `Silent Picture` mode it would read out the Liveview frame line by line. This does mean that you were still limited to [1720x974](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Unified/UserGuide#Shoot) (scroll down to `Silent Picture / Silent Pic HiRes / Slit-scan Pic`).
However I see in the [change log](https://bitbucket.org/hudson/magic-lantern/commits/all?search=slit) that this feature is removed from ML in March 2012 and that you are left with the video method + frame grabbing + still a low resolution.

I think the conclusion is that you can't take a high res slit-scan photo with ML.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want, but a way to make high resolution slit-scan photographs (or video!) is by shooting a video sequence with a DSLR and then post-processing it to create the slit-scan effect.

The Time Displacement effect from After Effects will give you the effect. [This tutorial](http://vimeo.com/71702373) is a good introduction to this technique.